# Restart Windows Service Based on SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to restart a windows service based on an SQL query (MS SQL Server). Details of the use case are at the bottom. Can someone please suggest a CMD/Powershell query for that? I will run that query on a scheduler.

.

.

Use Case:
The service "BcMsg" has to run 24x7 and perform some required tasks. When it throws an error, the service is running but is not doing its job. We need to restart it in that case. To check if it has run into an error, we can check its execution log in an SQL database.

Here is an explainer of the desired solution:

```
IF EXISTS(
SELECT 1
FROM [BcTable].[dbo].[LOG]
WHERE [EntryDate] >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,GETDATE()) AND [EntryMsg] LIKE '%Error%'
)

THEN
RESTART BcMsg.exe

ELSE
KEEP CHILLING
```

Comment: Did you try any research? There is a [restart service cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-service?view=powershell-7.1). A little more searching will surely find examples of how to use logic based on the result of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Powershell quite neatly with the `Invoke-SqlCmd` command:

```
if ( ( Invoke-Sqlcmd -HostName YourServer -Database YourDB -Query "SELECT 1 FROM [BcTable].[dbo].[LOG] WHERE [EntryDate] >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,GETDATE()) AND [EntryMsg] LIKE '%Error%'").Length -gt 0)
{
    Restart-Service -Name YourServiceName
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Had to spend some time on importing the SQL server module + getting the connection right using Instance instead of Host/Server but was able to do it once the logic was sorted.